# No Linker option in Visual Studio Project Properties

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, linker

I'm trying to add a library to a Visual Studio C++ project, however, when I go to project properties I only have options for,

```
Common Properties
    Startup Project
    Project Dependencies
    Debug Source File
Configuration Properites
    Configuration
```

Why can't I see the linker options?

Comment: Similar question: [DLL References in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809948/dll-references-in-visual-c)

Comment: Similar question: [How do I reference one VC++ project from another in the same project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201959/how-do-i-reference-one-vc-project-from-another-in-the-same-project)

Comment: Ive added the library directory to visual studio. My problem is i cant add the library as the option:
 Configuration Properties->Linker->Input Is not visible.

Comment: Normally i go to: Project Properties / Configuration Properties / Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies. But the linker option isn't visible

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am having the same issue. project is C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569189/i-dont-have-the-linker-option-in-visual-studio-2013-how-to-enable-it

Answer (score 49):

Updating answer for VS2012 to cover executable and libraries.

If your project is an executable then you need to navigate as such:
Myproject --> properties --> linker --> additional dependencies and add the dll or lib.

If you project is a library, there is no "linker" tab so you need to navigate as such:
Myproject -->properties --> Librarian --> additional dependencies and add the dll or lib

Comment: I am positive this a stupid question, but how do I know whether my project is an executable or a library?

Comment: @coffeenet In properties go to General tab then look at Configuration type. Should tell you if it's .exe, .lib, or .dll.

Comment: I don't have any configuration type in the general tab. 
Also, both ways do not work for me

Answer (score 32):

You are looking at the properties for the *Solution*.

You'll need to open the properties for the specific project within that solution.

Comment: I have two hundred projects - surely there must be a way to change common settings for all of them?

Comment: @Michael You saved my life

Answer (score 20):

Are you by any chance looking at a library project? Quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6476299/1094064):

> A library is just a collection of objects, which by definition have not been linked yet. The linker is not used to create the library, so it makes sense that there would be no linker options for it.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2013:

Go to: Project Properties -> Configuration Manager -> General.
There, under Project Defaults, change the Configuration Type to either Dynamic Library or Application. Click on Apply. Then you should see the Linker tab added to the menu on the left.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELP.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick note, in 2015 it is called "Configuration Properties", not "Configuration Manager", as that is something else.

Comment: What about 2019??

Comment: This worked for VS 2019 as well.

Answer (score 4):

If the Configuration Type (Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type) is set to Utility, then no linker option will be available.

Comment: Yes and I'm getting `error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'`, what has to be done in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Either you are looking at the "solution" level or at a file level (e.g. main.cpp). Move to project level and you will see the Linker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Visual Studio as an administrator. This works for me.